# Send a text from Emacs to Grammarly

Tags: text-editing, spell-checking

Is there a nice way to bind Emacs and Grammarly. This is what I wrote to myself. A very simple plugin that helps you to send a marked text to Grammarly. It is a very simple plugin, is there a better way?

https://github.com/mmagnus/emacs-grammarly

[image]

Comment: Looks basically OK. I see you're using the Mac OS X native app from Grammarly. It would be interesting to see your mode recognize what's available and use *that* (e.g. Chrome plugin on GNU/Linux machines). Also, I don't think you need to create the temp file. Rather just send the text to standard input (provided the native app can handle it).

Comment: I wonder what is your current workflow for using Grammarly with Emacs? Has there been any progress since then? I have Ubuntu 22.04; does it work there too?